# Edit view in asp.net mvc

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq

I have table call `AB_Product_vs_Field` in that table I have following columns

- Product_ID
- Field_ID
- Field_Value

once I pass `Product_ID` and `Field_ID` I want to find the relavant record in that table and load the relevant `Field_Value`.

So for that I wrote following code

```
    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult Edit(string Product_ID , string Field_ID)
    {
        if ((db.AB_Product_vs_Field.Any(u => u.Product_ID == Product_ID))&(db.AB_Product_vs_Field.Any(u => u.Field_ID == FieldID)))
        {           
            var product_values = new ProductEdit
            {
                ListProductFields = db.AB_Product_vs_Field.Where(p => p.Field_ID == FieldID).ToList(),
                ListProductLables = db.AB_ProductTypeCategoryField.Where(p => p.ProductFieldID == FieldID).ToList(),
                Pager = pager
            };

        return View(product_values);           

        }

    }
```

this is `ProductEdit` model class

```
    public class ProductEdit
    {
        public string Product_ID { get; set; }
        public string Field_ID { get; set; }
        public IList<AB_Product_vs_Field> ListProductFields { get; set; }
        public IList<AB_ProductTypeCategoryField> ListProductLables { get; set; }    

        public IEnumerable<string> Items { get; set; }
        public PaginationModel.Pager Pager { get; set; }


        public int PageSize { get; set; }
        public int PageCount { get; set; }
        public int CurrentPageIndex { get; set; }

    }
```

these are the relevant model classes

```
public partial class AB_ProductTypeCategoryField
{
    public string ProductFieldID { get; set; }
    public string ProductFieldNameEn { get; set; }        
}

public partial class AB_Product_vs_Field
{
    public string Product_ID { get; set; }
    public string Field_ID { get; set; }
    public string Field_Value { get; set; }               
}
```

this is the view of that edit view

```
@model albaraka.Models.ProductEdit

@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

    <div class="form-horizontal"> 
        @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" }) 
        @for (int i = 0; i < Model.ListProductFields.Count; i++)
        {
            <div class="form-group">
                @Html.LabelFor(x => x.ListProductLables[i].ProductFieldNameEn, Model.ListProductLables[i].ProductFieldNameEn, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                <div class="col-md-10">
                    @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.ListProductFields[i].Field_ID)
                    @Html.TextAreaFor(m => m.ListProductFields[i].Field_Value, new { @class = "form-control", @row = 5 })                  
                </div>
            </div>        

            <div class="form-group">
                <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                    <input type="submit" value="Save Details" class="btn btn-success" />
                </div>
            </div>

        }
    </div>
}
```

then I'm getting flowing error

> Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of
>   the collection. Parameter name: index

whats wrong with my approach , how to load properly ?

Comment: See your entire error. It will specify you where is the line that causes this error and what is the source file.

Comment: its this line `@Html.LabelFor(x => x.ListProductLables[i].ProductFieldNameEn, Model.ListProductLables[i].ProductFieldNameEn, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })`

Comment: IN controller fill it like  var abProduct =db.AB_Product_vs_Field.Where(p => p.Field_ID == FieldID).ToList();
                ListProductFields = from a in abProduct select new AB_Product_vs_Field {
                                    Product_ID = abProduct.Product_ID  ,
                                    Field_ID = abProduct.Field_ID ,
                                    Field_Value = abProduct.Field_Value 
                                    }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You loop is incrementing the `ListProductFields` collection, but inside you have

```
@Html.LabelFor(x => x.ListProductLables[i].ProductFieldNameEn....
```

I assume it should be

```
@Html.LabelFor(x => x.ListProductFields[i].someProperty
```

If `ListProductLables` does not contain exactly the same number of elements as `ListProductLables` , your will get the exception

Comment: I think this linq query generate the problem `ListProductFields = db.AB_Product_vs_Field.Where(p => p.Field_ID == FieldID).ToList(),`

I want to select specific row , but seems like its grabbing multiple rows , is it ?

Comment: If you only want one row, then use `.Where(p => p.Field_ID == FieldID).FirstOrDefault();` and make your property `public AB_Product_vs_Field ListProductFields { get; set; }` (i.e. not a collection). And ditto for `ListProductLables`. And of course you can then remove the loop in the view

Comment: I want to find a specific row using 2 parameters So I tried like this 
`ListProductFields = db.AB_Product_vs_Field.Where((db.AB_Product_vs_Field.Any(u => u.Product_ID == Product_ID)) & (db.AB_Product_vs_Field.Any(u => u.Field_ID == Field_ID))).ToList(),`
but this has a comiple time error

Comment: ahh okay sorted it like this `ListProductFields = db.AB_Product_vs_Field.Where((p => p.Field_ID == FieldID)).Where(p =>p.Product_ID == Product_ID).ToList(),` sorry for the bother

Comment: Your still using `.ToList()` Are you expecting to return a collection or just a single object?

Comment: just a single object

Comment: And you can simplify it to `ListProductFields = db.AB_Product_vs_Field.Where(p => p.Field_ID == FieldID && p.Product_ID == Product_ID).ToList()` (or `.FirstOrDefault()` if you want just a single object)

Comment: In that case use `.FirstOrDefault()` and change the property to be a single object (not `IList<T>`) which means you can simplify the view by deleting the loop.

Comment: not a part of this problem , can I refer two model class per one view ?

Comment: because I want to give same model class for add view and edit view

Comment: Not exactly sure what you mean. You cannot have 2 models in a view - e.g. `@model A` and `@model B`, but you can have one view model combining 2 other models. (or you can use the `@Html.Action()` method to load views of different models.

Comment: once I remove `@for` in viewpage how can I avoid the `ListProductLables[i]`  ??

Comment: If the model property is now `public AB_Product_vs_Field ListProductFields { get; set; }` rather than `public IList<AB_Product_vs_Field> ListProductFields { get; set; }` (because you use `.FirstOrDefault()` then you do not need an indexer (its not a collection) - it will be just `@Html.TextAreaFor(m => m.ListProductFields.Field_Value, .....)`

Answer (score 1):

Most potential reason:

```
@for (int i = 0; i < Model.ListProductFields.Count; i++)
        {
            <div class="form-group">
                @Html.LabelFor(x => x.ListProductLables[i].ProductFieldNameEn, Model.ListProductLables[i].ProductFieldNameEn, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
```

Here you are assuming in `for` loop condition that `ListProductFields.Count` will be `=` to `ProductFieldNameEn.Count` but they seem to be not equal count.

Answer (score 0):

You need to change the '&' operator to an '&&' operator :

```
  if ((db.AB_Product_vs_Field.Any(u => u.Product_ID == Product_ID))&&(db.AB_Product_vs_Field.Any(u => u.Field_ID == FieldID)))
```

Also in the view you are referencing the wrong array:

change :

```
   @Html.LabelFor(x => x.ListProductLables[i].ProductFieldNameEn, Model.ListProductLables[i].ProductFieldNameEn, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
```

to :

```
   @Html.LabelFor(x => x.ListProductFields[i].ProductFieldNameEn, Model.ListProductFields[i].ProductFieldNameEn, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
```